# How can I convert LPWSTR into &str

Tags: string, networking, rust, ffi

In my previous question I asked how to cast `LPVOID` to `LPNETRESOURCEW`. And it goes well.   I have a struct of `NETRESOURCEW` with fields:

```
    dwScope: DWORD,
    dwType: DWORD,
    dwDisplayType: DWORD,
    dwUsage: DWORD,
    lpLocalName: LPWSTR,
    lpRemoteName: LPWSTR,
    lpComment: LPWSTR,
    lpProvider: LPWSTR,
```

According to docs `nr.lpRemoteName` is `LPWSTR` -> `*mut u16`. I've tried using `OsString::from_wide` but nothing got well. How can I convert `LPWSTR` into Rust `*str` or `String` and print it in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally done by marshalling the string pointer into a slice.
First you need to get the length of the string / slice which can be done like this if the string is null-terminated:

```rust
let length = (0..).take_while(|&i| *my_string.offset(i) != 0).count();
```

Then you can create the slice like so

```rust
let slice = std::slice::from_raw_parts(my_string, length);
```

and finally convert the slice into an [`OsString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html):

```rust
let my_rust_string = OsString::from_wide(slice).to_string_lossy().into_owned();
```

### Update due to comment

I have verified that the given approach works as can be reproduced using this snippet:

```rust
use std::{ffi::OsString, os::windows::prelude::OsStringExt};

use windows_sys::w;

fn main() {
    let my_string = w!("This is a UTF-16 string.");

    let slice;
    unsafe {
        let length = (0..).take_while(|&i| *my_string.offset(i) != 0).count();
        slice = std::slice::from_raw_parts(my_string, length);
    }

    let my_rust_string = OsString::from_wide(slice).to_string_lossy().into_owned();
    println!("{}", my_rust_string);
}
```

If you get a `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` it is most likely because your string is not null-terminated in which case you would need to determine the length of the string in another way or preallocate the buffer.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that `my_string` needs to be of the type `*const u16`. Further, it might also be worth pointing out that the first two statements have to be done inside if an `unsafe{}` block, as they dereference pointers. Once you have the slice, no unsafe code is required any more.

Comment: The variable should probably be named something other than `my_os_string`, since it holds a `String`, not an `OsString`.

Comment: (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION) I got this error.

Comment: @NikoBosko, that is probably an issue with how you get the length of your string. This answer assumes the string is null terminated and can lead to a segfault if that is not the case. You also need to be warry of cases where you are given the length separately since the length may be measured in bytes instead of `WCHAR`s (`u16`).